# Shrimpy API does not Accept Public/Private Keys

Tags: python, api, cryptocurrency

We are trying to use [Shrimpy's](https://developers.shrimpy.io/docs/?python#introduction) APIs. We used the code provided by them from [here](https://github.com/shrimpy-dev/shrimpy-python). For unknown reasons, when we provide it with our own public and private keys, the code crashes and returns us the following message:

> StatusCodeError: 500 - "{"error":"Invalid IP address, API Key, or signature"}"

We used both the Python and JS codes. The error rises when we set the keys as follows:

```
import shrimpy

public_key = 'PUBLIC_KEY'
private_key = 'PRIVATE_KEY'
api_client = shrimpy.ShrimpyApiClient(public_key, private_key)
raw_token = api_client.get_token()
client = shrimpy.ShrimpyWsClient(error_handler, raw_token['token'])
```

Here, we get the error I mentioned before. I used the API keys right after their creation and I am confidence about their credibility (public key's length is 64 and private key's length is 128). I created them couple of times but nothing happened. When I call `client.get_status()`, it shows that the keys are not set:

> {'apiKeyAccepted': False,
> 'apiNonceAccepted': False,
> 'apiSignatureAccepted': False,
> 'ipAccepted': True,
> 'requestsRemaining': 8}

I cannot understand if their API is not working or is there anything that I did not consider.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue today when I integrate Shrimpy into my app, but I'm writing my own RestClient using Rails so I guess my issue comes from header signing. Not sure with your case, but you can check signing header part in here https://developers.shrimpy.io/docs/?python#creating-a-request

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: @Tiktac, I'm still getting the same response. Would tell me more about your headers? they were set according to the link you provided?

Comment: Are you using their python/js lib? If so it's not problem with request header signing because they already did it for you. I'm writing my own http request, so I have to sign it manually. Did you try to whitelist your IP address on Shrimpy dashboard?

Comment: I found the problem. Our department mistakenly, provided us the account of dashboard.shrimpy, instead of developers.shrimpy. I created the account and it is now working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because our department provided us the wrong account. It was  *dashboard.shrimpy.ir* not from *developers.shrimpy.io*.